# Prove the primary decomposition is irredundant

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I meet the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $L$ be a $R$-submodule of $M$ s.t. $L\neq M$. Then there exists a family $\{ L(Q) \}_{Q\in\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L)}$ of $R$-submodules of $M$ s.t.
>
> 1) $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L(Q))=\{Q\} $ for every $Q\in\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L)$, and
>
> 2) $\bigcap_{Q\in\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L)}L(Q)=L$.

So I'll sum up the proof:

Set $\mathcal F=\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L)$. For each $Q\in\mathcal F$ we can find $L(Q)\supset L$ s.t. $\operatorname{Ass}_R(L(Q)/L)=\mathcal F\setminus \{Q\}$, so $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L(Q))=\{Q\}$. We set $N=\bigcap_{Q\in \mathcal F}L(Q) $. Then $L\subset N$. Also,
$$\operatorname{Ass}_R(N/L) \subseteq \operatorname{Ass}_R(L(Q)/L)=\mathcal F\setminus \{Q\}$$
for all $Q$. So $\operatorname{Ass}_R(N/L)= \emptyset$, or $N=L$.

I can understand the proof, the daunting part is the Remark after that:

> REMARK: If $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M/L)$ is finite, then the decomposition in (2) is irredundant.

So help me with this REMARK, I don't know why it happens. Thank you.

Comment: Is M finitely generated?

Comment: Your primes $Q \in Ass_R (M/L)$ seems like all distinct, in this case you get a minimal intersection in (2) and finiteness implies that decomposition in $(2)$ is irredundant. For more general case see Eisenbud's book corollary 3.8 and theorem 3.10.